# How do you align equations parts vertically?

Tags: vertical-alignment

I have read many other solutions but this situation seems unique.

```
\documentclass{exam}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
 \begin{questions}
\question Simplify the following:
    \begin{multicols}{4}
        \begin{parts}
            \part $8^\frac{2}{3}$
            \part $\dfrac{16^{\frac{2}{3}}}{16^{\frac{1}{6}}}$ 
            \part $9^\frac{1}{3}\cdot 9^{-\frac{5}{6}}$
            \part $\left(25^{\frac{1}{3}}\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}$
        \end{parts}
    \end{multicols}
 \end{questions}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The heights of the four part letters is different, because the different heights of the formulas. The following example defines `\vphantomB` with an invisible box of the greatest height of part (b):

```
\documentclass{exam}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
 \begin{questions}
\question Simplify the following:
    \begin{multicols}{4}
        \def\vphantomB{\leavevmode\vphantom{$\dfrac{16^{\frac{2}{3}}}{}$}}
        \begin{parts}
            \part \vphantomB $8^\frac{2}{3}$
            \part $\dfrac{16^{\frac{2}{3}}}{16^{\frac{1}{6}}}$
            \part \vphantomB $9^\frac{1}{3}\cdot 9^{-\frac{5}{6}}$
            \part \vphantomB $\left(25^{\frac{1}{3}}\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}$
        \end{parts}
    \end{multicols}
 \end{questions}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Answer (score 6):

you can use the package `enumitem` instead:

```
documentclass{exam}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
\begin{document}
 \begin{questions}
\question Simplify the following:

\begin{enumerate*}[label*=(\alph*),itemjoin={\hfill}]
  \item $8^\frac{2}{3}$
  \item $\dfrac{16^{\frac{2}{3}}}{16^{\frac{1}{6}}}$ 
  \item $9^\frac{1}{3}\cdot 9^{-\frac{5}{6}}$
  \item $\left(25^{\frac{1}{3}}\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}$
\end{enumerate*}
\end{questions}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: In this solution, if you have too many items, there is no vertical alignment betwen the items in different lines.